# How do I change the column width in Plotly Python graphs?

Tags: python, plotly

when output without the width=1 parameter, the columns are too wide when specifying the parameter, the graph is not drawn
this is with the parameter width=1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzipP.png)

this is without the width=1 parameter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWjgO.png)

```
fig_month = go.Figure(data=go.Bar(x=biom_enrollments_by_month['Месяц'], 
                                  y=biom_enrollments_by_month['Дата'], 
                                  width=1))

fig_month.update_layout(
    xaxis=dict(
        rangeselector=dict(
            buttons=list([
                dict(count=1,
                     label="1m",
                     step="month",
                     stepmode="backward"),
                dict(count=1,
                     label="MTD",
                     step="month",
                     stepmode="todate"),
                dict(count=10,
                     label="10d",
                     step="day",
                     stepmode="backward"),
                dict(step="all")
            ])
        ),
        rangeslider=dict(
            visible=True
        ),
        type="date"
    )
)
```

Comment: What kind of data do you use to create your graphs? Can you submit sample data?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.